# Centre a DIV based on viewable browser space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to centre a DIV (`form`) based on the presently viewable browser space, and one that takes into account how far up or down a page I have scrolled.  I would like the form centred as and when I press a button.  My attempt is below.  The problem with my attempt is that if I have scrolled down a page far enough for instance, the form is not entered, but is centred if I scroll all the way up the page again.

If I have scrolled down the page, and want the form to appear, the first image shows what i get.

If I am at the top of the page, then the form is properly centred.

PS:- **No** jQuery solutions please

CSS for div `#docForm`

```css
#docForm {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 425px;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  z-index: 10000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #b8b8b8;
  color: #484848;
}
```

[image: When I have scrolled down the page and want the form to show. this is what i see]

[image: If I am at the top of the page, then the form is properly centred]

Comment: Could it be possible to show us what you mean using a snippet? This is really vague.

Comment: If you wrap it in a `position:fixed` element which is 100% wide and high it should be fine. Position fixed elements don't scroll.

Comment: Please don't put comments such as "no jquery solutions please" in the title - if anything, this should go in the description of the question (but not tagging it with jquery should in theory also be sufficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#docForm {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

or if you want to use flex, create a div with class formContainer, put your form inside of it and then:

```
.formContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: awesome. just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a fixed width and height, you can do this by setting the left and top to the center of the screen, then offsetting the container by half of it's width and height:

```
#docForm {
  width: 600px;
  height: 425px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -311px  /*  -(width + padding*2 + border_width*2) / 2)  */
  margin-top: -223px   /*  -(height + padding*2 + border_width*2) / 2) */
}
```

All settings not relevant to the solution omitted in this answer, however note that you must not set `right` or `bottom`, or you will get unintended results.

In contrast to using [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) or [translate](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d), this will be compatible with browsers that don't support CSS Level 3.